# Absolute position for html to pdf itextsharp

Tags: itext

Hi I was trying to convert html to pdf using below code . It seems like if my html content has a absolute position then the parser is ignoring it.

This is a sample html i tried to convert

STATE OF MARYLAND

var cssText = string.Empty;
            var htmlText = string.Empty;

```
        htmlText = _busrenew.GetLicenseTemplate("LicenseTemplate");
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
        document.Open();
        using (var cssMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cssText)))
        {
            using (var htmlMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlText)))
            {
                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, htmlMemoryStream, cssMemoryStream);
            }
        }
        document.Close();
        var pdfContent = new PdfContent
        {
            MemoryStream = memoryStream,
            FileName = "SomeName"
        };
```

Comment: The html i tried to convert is <div style="position:absolute;left:161.56px;top:130.47px" class="cls_004"><span class="cls_004">STATE OF MARYLAND</span></div>

Answer (score 0):

Its not supported use position relative
When using position relative the only other change you will need to make to accommodate this is changing the pixels for the top

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me in the iText HtmlToPdf. Place this between style block.

```
 #img_test {
        position: absolute;
        top: 2px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: -1;
        
    }
```